# How to fix Secure Boot error "Image failed to verify with *ACCESS DENIED*" on startup?

Tags: boot, uefi, security, lenovo, secure-boot

When I started up my machine this morning (I have Secure Boot and UEFI only enabled) I got this error (sorry for low quality image):

[image]

What does it mean by `Image failed to verify with *ACCESS DENIED*`? After I pressed `OK` I managed to get into my BIOS and turn off Secure Boot as well as settings the UEFI only option to accept both UEFI and Legacy, this seemed to do the trick and now it boots, however I am unable to set it so that Secure Boot is on again and this poses a security threat to me so I am wondering what the problem is here? And why I got the error? I mean, is there error something to worry about? And why did it `*ACCESS DENIED*` me?

The only thing that I can think of that I might have done last night before this issue this morning occurred is receive some security updates for grub and some other stuff:

[image]

So basically I need to know what the error means, why I got it, and how to fix this situation. I mean, could this error mean that I have been compromised in some way and should do a fresh install or something? Or is it just a malfunction? And if so, how do I fix it so that I can use Secure Boot again?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 on a Lenovo B590.

**Information Update:**

The output from the command `efibootmgr` is:

```
BootCurrent: 000E
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 000E,0000,0001,0002,0003,000C,0006,0007,0008,0009,000A,000B,000D
Boot0000  Setup
Boot0001  Boot Menu
Boot0002  Diagnostic Splash Screen
Boot0003  Lenovo Diagnostics
Boot0004  Startup Interrupt Menu
Boot0005  Rescue and Recovery
Boot0006* USB CD
Boot0007* USB FDD
Boot0008* ATAPI CD1
Boot0009* ATA HDD0
Boot000A* ATA HDD1
Boot000B* ATA HDD2
Boot000C* USB HDD
Boot000D* PCI LAN
Boot000E* ubuntu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRUB packages were updated yesterday (December 15, 2015) : `2.02~beta2-29ubuntu0.2`.
Maybe something went wrong during the upgrade, but there shouldn't be a security issue.

Change the BIOS settings back to the state in which you had installed Ubuntu.
Then reinstall the GRUB boot loader to your Ubuntu installation  in EFI mode.

Boot from the Ubuntu installation media - open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo mount /dev/sd*** /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sd*
update-grub
```

Note:

`sd*` = disk | `sd**` = efi partition | `sd***` = system partition
To identify the disk and partition numbers you can use GParted.

Boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu as the default operating system.

USN-Reference : [Ubuntu Security Notice 2836-1: GRUB vulnerability](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2836-1/)

In case it does not work, you alternatively can try the boot-repair tool.
Boot from the Ubuntu installation media, open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Answer (score 5):

According to https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1528345 this was caused by Ubuntu shipping security updates for grub in an incorrect way, and can be fixed by installing the package grub-efi-amd64-signed, and then reenabling secure boot in the BIOS.  This worked for me.  (I also checked that reinstalling the package caused `shimx64.efi` to show up in the output of `efibootmgr -v` instead of `grubx64.efi`, which was there while the problem was present.)

Answer (score 3):

First, go back into your firmware and disable the CSM ("legacy boot") support. If you were booting in a pure-EFI environment, as it sounds like you were, that option will do you no good, and could come back to bite you later. (See [my page on the subject](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for more information on CSM's problems.)

Second, the error message indicates that your computer attempted to boot a boot loader that was not signed with an authorized Secure Boot key. (Some of the messages warning of such violations are pretty obtuse -- they vary from one EFI to another, and in some cases from one follow-on program to another, depending on where the violation occurred.) Such a message popping up after the computer has been booting successfully, and with no changes to your boot programs or firmware settings, is a big red flag.

I saw no mention of updates to either GRUB or Shim, so your boot process *should not* have been affected by those updates. OTOH, it could be that something else has modified the boot path. This might be an innocent change that's gone badly and caused a glitch -- for instance, if you're triple-booting with another Linux distribution, it might have changed the boot path to an unsigned GRUB. If that's the case, you can change the boot order back to Ubuntu's GRUB (via Shim) with `efibootmgr` -- type `sudo efibootmgr -v` to see the current boot order (on the `BootOrder` line) and options (the bulk of the output). Locate the line for Ubuntu that launches via Shim and use the `-o` option to change the order so that it's first, as in `sudo efibootmgr -o 0009,0000,001B` if the desired entry is `Boot0009` and two alternatives are `Boot0000` and `Boot001B`. Another possibility is that an unrelated Windows update has interfered with GRUB. (Microsoft has the ability to update most computers' Secure Boot keys, and if they've bungled that or deliberately blacklisted Ubuntu's Shim for some reason, you might see the error you've described.)

There's a small chance that something malicious is happening -- some piece of malware might have installed itself in your boot path. If that's happened, then by disabling Secure Boot, you've already enabled the malware to run. There's no telling what the consequences might be if this is the case. I don't mean to alarm you; the odds of this having happened are low. If this *has* happened, though, it will take expert TLC to recover your computer, since pre-boot malware is notoriously difficult to extricate.

Updating your GRUB configuration is unlikely to do any good, although there's a slim chance that it might if you switch GRUB from booting an unsigned to a signed version of the kernel. (The last I checked, Ubuntu's GRUB would boot unsigned kernels, but that might change in the future. Some other GRUBs, like the one used by Fedora, are stricter and will boot only signed kernels.)

You can check your boot path with `efibootmgr` and verify that it's booting through Shim by default -- that is, the boot loader for the first item in the boot order should be `EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`. If that's *not* the case, then you may be able to change the boot order back. If it *is* the case, then perhaps your `shimx64.efi` binary has become damaged (or worse, replaced by malware). Completely re-installing GRUB might fix the problem. (Boot Repair can do this fairly easily.)

Comment: What is the package name for Boot Repair?

Comment: Also, you've succeeded in alarming me! I'm probably the most paranoid person you'll ever know (it's in the name ;))! :D

Comment: Also, Ubuntu is the only OS running, well or *should* be running... I don't have it dual-booted with anything else or triple-booted etc...

Comment: Boot Repair isn't in a standard package; see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) for details.

Comment: I have updated my question with the output of `efibootmgr`, however is there a special option I need to use with it or something to get the information you talked about?

Comment: Ok, I fixed it with Boot Repair, so does that rule out the possibility of it being malicious or could that still be the case?

Comment: `efibootmgr -v` would have been more informative, but probably not now that you've fixed it. My suspicion is that something altered the boot path to launch GRUB directly rather than via Shim, but I can't be sure of that.

Comment: So do you think that it is still possible that there is some malware in machine which was behind this and that it could still cause me problems?

Comment: I can't rule out that possibility; but I also can't rule out the possibility that any other random system has malware installed. You could always try scanning for known malware, although tools to do this are more common in Windows than in Linux.

Comment: Just normal malware in my machine with an AV? Or specifically pre-boot malware that would probably be scanned for using a LiveUSB or something?

Comment: I'm seeing the same error, and also seeing that disabling Secure Boot fixes it.  (And there was a grub update (grub-common, grub2-common, grub-efi-amd64-bin, grub-efi-amd64) since I'd previously rebooted.)

How would I tell from `efibootmgr -v`  what happened?

I'm seeing ubuntu (0014) as first in the boot order, and the 0014 line is:

`Boot0014* ubuntu HD(2,GPT,01d19882-a94c-40c5-8f5c-a8d1be43c4a9,0x1f4800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)`

Comment: If `0014` is first in the `BootOrder`, and if it points to `grubx64.efi`, as yours does, then Shim is being bypassed. Shim is a requirement for Secure Boot under Ubuntu (assuming standard EFI Secure Boot keys from Microsoft), so that's the problem. If an update created this condition from a formerly-working setup, then that's a bug that you should report, as described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: OK, thanks.   Reported https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1528345